# 2D array to 2D doubly linked list by recursion

Tags: python, doubly-linked-list

Given a 2D array, create a 2D doubly linked list by only using recursion. Every number in the list must have 4 pointers (up, down, right, left) and needs to be linked to every number next to it (If no number, then just 'None')

```py
import numpy as np

class Node:

""" Node class
    
        up
         |
left - data - right
         |
       down
"""

   def __init__(self, data):
       self.data = data
       self.right = None
       self.left = None
       self.up = None
       self.down = None

def constructDoublyLinkedListRecursion(arr):

    """ Converts a 2D array into a 2D doubly linked list by calling
    the recursee constructDLLRecursiveStep.
 
    input:
        arr: 2D array to turn into a 2D DLL
        
    output:
        head (top left node) of the 2D DLL of the input arr.
    """
    return constructDLLRecursiveStep(arr, 0, 0, None)

def constructDLLRecursiveStep(arr, y, x, curr):
    """ Recursively construct the 2D DLL from the given array.
    This is the "recursee" of constructDoublyLinkedListRecursion.
    
    input:
        arr: The 2D array to construct the 2D DLL from.
        y: y-coordinate of the array to get the value from.
        x: x-coordinate of the array to get the value from.
        curr: The current node to connect the new node from.
        
    output:
        new_node: The newly created node which connects to curr node.
    """
        
    return new_node
```

This is what i did so far:

```py
def constructDLLRecursiveStep(arr, y, x, curr):
    
    arrDim = arr.shape[1]
    
    if(y >= arrDim or x >= arrDim):
        return None;
    
    new_node = Node(arr[y,x])
        
    if(x > 0):
        new_node.left = curr
    else:
        new_node.left = None
        
    if(y > 0):
        new_node.up = curr
    else:
        new_node.up = None
    
    new_node.right = constructDLLRecursiveStep(arr, y, x+1, new_node)
    
    new_node.down = constructDLLRecursiveStep(arr, y+1, x, new_node)
    
    return new_node
```

Display function

```py
def display(dll_ptr):
    """ Prints the 2D dll according to their positions similar to 
        printing a 2D array.
    
    input:
        dll_ptr: the head (most upper left node) of a 2D dll.
        
    output:
        None
    """
    right_ptr = None
    down_ptr = dll_ptr
    
    while down_ptr != None:
        right_ptr = down_ptr
        
        while right_ptr != None:
            msg = f"{right_ptr.data} | "
            for i, direction in enumerate([("up", right_ptr.up), ("right", right_ptr.right), ("down", right_ptr.down), ("left", right_ptr.left)]):
                direction_str, direction_ptr = direction
                if direction_ptr: msg += f"{direction_str}: {direction_ptr.data}"
                else: msg += f"{direction_str}: None"
                msg += ", "
            print(msg) 
            right_ptr = right_ptr.right
        print()
        down_ptr = down_ptr.down
```

I am getting this output which shows that there's an issue with the up-pointer:

```
"""
Input 2D array:
[[9 4 0 8 6]
 [4 3 2 2 7]
 [9 7 3 9 2]
 [8 7 3 6 2]
 [9 4 6 5 3]]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

constructDoublyLinkedListRecursion output:
9 4 0 8 6 
4 3 2 2 7
9 7 3 9 2
8 7 3 6 2
9 4 6 5 3

constructDoublyLinkedListRecursion output:
9 | up: None, right: 4, down: 4, left: None, 
4 | up: None, right: 0, down: 3, left: 9, 
0 | up: None, right: 8, down: 2, left: 4, 
8 | up: None, right: 6, down: 2, left: 0, 
6 | up: None, right: None, down: 7, left: 8, 

4 | up: 9, right: 3, down: 9, left: None, 
3 | up: 4, right: 2, down: 7, left: 4, 
2 | up: 3, right: 2, down: 3, left: 3, 
2 | up: 2, right: 7, down: 9, left: 2, 
7 | up: 2, right: None, down: 2, left: 2, 

9 | up: 4, right: 7, down: 8, left: None, 
7 | up: 9, right: 3, down: 7, left: 9, 
3 | up: 7, right: 9, down: 3, left: 7, 
9 | up: 3, right: 2, down: 6, left: 3, 
2 | up: 9, right: None, down: 2, left: 9, 

8 | up: 9, right: 7, down: 9, left: None, 
7 | up: 8, right: 3, down: 4, left: 8, 
3 | up: 7, right: 6, down: 6, left: 7, 
6 | up: 3, right: 2, down: 5, left: 3, 
2 | up: 6, right: None, down: 3, left: 6, 

9 | up: 8, right: 4, down: None, left: None, 
4 | up: 9, right: 6, down: None, left: 9, 
6 | up: 4, right: 5, down: None, left: 4, 
5 | up: 6, right: 3, down: None, left: 6, 
3 | up: 5, right: None, down: None, left: 5, 
"""
```

Comment: You haven't tried anything and you are asking for a direct solution! Try it and ask only specific issues here

Comment: I have added my solution. There's an issue with the up-pointer which i can't figure out :))

Comment: Can you provide the code for your output display? I don't see a problem in the recursion logic.

Comment: I have added the display function. I'm pretty sure the issue lies within the recursions step-function though.

Comment: It does output the right matrix, however, i can't seem to fix the up-pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you are recurring almost unconditionally in both directions. That means that the node at index 1, 1 will be created via two different recursion paths: once by first recurring with x + 1 and later on with y + 1, and a second time when y + 1 is being called and there a recursive call is made with x + 1. The total number of recursive calls far exceeds the number of nodes you really need to create, as all possible (zig-zag) paths through the matrix are being made.

One solution is to only make a recursive call with y + 1 when x is zero. That will initiate the process to create the whole row (with the x + 1 recursion). The only thing to take care of is to "nit" those nodes to the corresponding nodes just above them. But this you can achieve by walking from the left side node upwards and then take the node at its right.

Here is the corrected code:

```
def constructDLLRecursiveStep(arr, y, x, curr):
    leny, lenx = arr.shape
    if y >= leny or x >= lenx: 
        return None

    new_node = Node(arr[y,x])
    if x == 0: # Came from above
        new_node.up = curr
    else: # Came from the left
        new_node.left = curr
        if y > 0: # Link to row above, by walking "the block"
            curr.up.right.down = new_node
            new_node.up = curr.up.right

    new_node.right = constructDLLRecursiveStep(arr, y, x + 1, new_node)
    if x == 0: # Recur downwards
        new_node.down = constructDLLRecursiveStep(arr, y + 1, 0, new_node)
    return new_node
```