# How to converts a 2D array into a 2D doubly linked list with loops in Python

Tags: for-loop, nodes, doubly-linked-list

the 2D array has been given and I need to use a for-loop to  converts a 2D array into a 2D doubly linked list. how can I do that? thank you!

`
import numpy as np

class Node:
""" Node class

```
        up
         |
left - data - right
         |
       down
"""

def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.right = None
    self.left = None
    self.up = None
    self.down = None
```

def constructDoublyLinkedListLoop(arr):
' Converts a 2D array into a 2D doubly linked list with loops.

```
input:
    arr: 2D array to turn into a 2D DLL
    
output:
    top_left_ptr: head (top left node) of the 2D DLL of the input arr.
'

return top_left_ptr`
```

Comment: Seems homework that has been asked before [with askers running away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71783568/how-to-convert-2d-array-to-2d-doubly-linked-list) when they have the answer. Sorry, I am moving on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [2D array to 2D doubly linked list by recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71868285/2d-array-to-2d-doubly-linked-list-by-recursion)